# Linear Algebra: Vector Spaces with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

[image]

I did part (b) by using the row equivalence relation as A=(u1, u2, ..., uk) is in rows.

I'm not able to do part (a) as the ui^T vectors in B are in columns. Is there any theorem or result which can be used?

Comment: The only way $\;B\;$ is a $\;n\times k\;$ matrix is if $\;u_i\;$ is a **row vector** and, thus $\;u_i^t\;$ is a column vector. This is against most widely definitions I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

In $\;Q\;$, the number of zero rows, say $\;\ell\;$ , is the number of linearly *dependent* rows, and thus $\;n-\ell\;$ is the row rank of $\;A\;$  which equals its column rank, and thus $\;n-\ell\;$ is the number of linearly independent vectors in $\;u_1,..,u_k\;$, and thus the only possibility is that $\;\ell=0\;$ for  Span$\,\{u_1,...,u_k\}=\Bbb R^n\;$ , which means, of course, that $\;k\ge n\;$ .

With this, and filling up some minor details, both parts in (a) are answered.